# How to set cookie value to httponly in datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am trying to set a cookie in data power for the UI to consume, but now we have a peculiar situation where we have to make the cookie httponly. Can we do that in data power httponly. If so please let us know how to create one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code sample can let you set cookie value.
`<dp:set-http-response-header name="'cookie'" value="'123456'"/>`